# Lift to Maybe using a predicate

Tags: haskell

I'm searching for something like

```
liftPredMaybe :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Maybe a
liftPredMaybe p a
  | p a = Just a
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

Is there such a function in Haskell already?

Comment: https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%28a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+Maybe+a

Comment: The above comment provides links to several duplicate implementations in multiple non-standard packages, so I'd say the answer is "No".

Comment: Thanks. I'll just roll my own then.

Comment: Can be crafted, like `liftPredMaybe p = listToMaybe . (filter p) . (:[])`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not quite a ready-made solution, but with `guard` (from `Control.Monad`) and `(<$)` (from `Data.Functor`) we can write:

```
ensure :: Alternative f => (a -> Bool) -> a -> f a
ensure p a = a <$ guard (p a)
```

(Thanks to Daniel Wagner for suggesting a nice name for this function.)

A more pointfree spelling of dubious taste is `\p -> (<$) <*> guard . p`.

Comment: This is my preferred spelling, and I've frequently included it in projects. I like the name `ensure`, because it fits well with the "0-1 nondeterminism" interpretation of `Maybe` and with the "n-way nondeterminism" interpretation of `[]`.

Comment: @DanielWagner `ensure` is a very good name. One nice little thing about this spelling is that `guard @Maybe` is one half of the isomorphism between `Bool` and `Maybe ()`.

Comment: It is strange to call those "golf spellings" when the "ungolfed" spelling, `\p a -> a <$ guard (p a)`, is as short or shorter (and more readable by far!).

Comment: @DanielWagner Good point... I have changed the wording a bit.

Comment: @DanielWagner FWIW, I was just told that this combinator exists in *protolude*, [which calls it `guarded`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/protolude-0.2.2/docs/Protolude.html#v:guarded).

Comment: A very straightforward implementation is `\p a -> if p a then pure a else empty`. It can be spun into a prettier golf spelling, namely `liftA2 (bool empty) pure`.

Answer (score 6):

One way to compose it is like this, using `Control.Monad`:

```
liftPredM :: MonadPlus m => (a -> Bool) -> a -> m a
liftPredM p = mfilter p . return
```

Another alternative is to use `Data.Foldable`:

```
liftPredF :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Maybe a
liftPredF f = find f . pure
```

This is, however, less general, so I'd lean towards favouring the `MonadPlus`-based implementation.

In both cases, though, the idea is to first lift a 'naked' value into a container using either `pure` or `return`, and then apply a filter. Often, you don't need to declare an actual function for this; instead, you can just inline the composition where you need it.

Examples:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> liftPredMaybe even 42 :: Maybe Integer
Just 42
Prelude Control.Monad> liftPredMaybe (even . length) "foo" :: Maybe String
Nothing
Prelude Control.Monad> liftPredMaybe (odd . length) "foo" :: Maybe String
Just "foo"
```

Comment: [1/2] (1) You'll probably want to replace `pure` in `liftPredF` with a function for a concrete functor (e.g. `(:[])` or `Just`). As written, the compiler rejects it due to type ambiguity unless `ExtendedDefaultingRules` is enabled (or [if you are in GHCi](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci), which enables it by default).(2) By the way, thanks for giving me one more example of the `Foldable` instance for `Maybe` being potentially useful: `find @Maybe :: (a -> Bool) -> Maybe a -> Maybe a`

Comment: [2/2] (3) If one is willing to bring in [`Data.Witherable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable-0.2/docs/Data-Witherable.html), `liftPredMaybe f = filter f . Just` becomes possible.